# Distance Calculation between US Zipcodes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, distance

I have Zipcode, City and State stored as variables for each user. I need to calculate and display the distance  in miles between all users from the database and the current user.

I came across Geo-magic and Geo-distance ruby gems but they use lat and lon for calculation.

Would like to acheive something like this 
https://www.freemaptools.com/distance-between-usa-zip-codes.htm
https://www.mapdevelopers.com/distance_from_to.php

Would like some help to implement this in rails in the most efficient way. TIA.

Comment: To my mind, lat and long would indeed be the most efficient solution for this; maintain a map of zip code to lat/long, work out difference between lat/long, convert to miles.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Geokit](https://github.com/geokit/geokit) gem. This gem can give you the distance between places based on zip code or address. But this gem will use google Gmaps/Bing maps.

Example:

```
a=Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode '140 Market St, San Francisco, CA'

b=Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode '789 Geary St, San Francisco, CA'

a.distance_to(b) # Get the distance between 'a' and 'b'
```

Check the gem home page for more usage.

Comment: Tried multiple geocoders as mentioned in https://github.com/geokit/geokit. All geocoding returns nil

Answer (score 0):

The [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) gem is also a good option.

However, as the other posters have indicated, at some point you're going to need to translate your location data down to latitude/longitude. You can find databases [such as this one from SoftwareTools](https://softwaretools.com/) that can translate zip codes to latitude/longitude, but there's not a lot of precision. Zip codes are somewhat deceptive; they vary greatly in terms of size, and their boundaries change with some frequency.

For example, zip code 89049 covers [an area of 10,000 square miles](https://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2013/07/01/197623129/the-zip-code-turns-50-today-here-are-9-that-stand-out), so your distance calculation could be by off by over a hundred miles depending on where in the zip code the user was located.

You'd be better off using a geolocation tool to translate each user's street address to a latitude/longitude and using that for your distance calculations. The [Haversine gem](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/haversine) can help with that, or if you use PostgreSQL, you can use the [earthdistance module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/earthdistance.html).

(I have no relation to SoftwareTools other than as a satisfied customer.)